# How to disable double tap on spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, double-click

Double tapping on spinner displays 2 menus. How to disable double tap?

Tried adding `TouchListeners` as shown below

```
private static final int CLICK_DELAY = 500;
private long lastMenuClickTime = 0;

actionsSpinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastMenuClickTime > CLICK_DELAY) {
              lastMenuClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

              return false;
            }
          }
          return true;
        }
      });
```

But this adds up some delay in executing click operation and the main issue is first click even after **CLICK_DELAY** doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do

```
 public static void disableTouch(final View v, long timeInMiliSec) {
        v.setEnabled(false);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }, timeInMiliSec);
    }
```

This function disable view for specified time

**Example:**

```
actionsSpinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          disableTouch(actionsSpinner, CLICK_DELAY)
          //do your other stuff here 

          return false;
        }
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: we cannot add onClickListener  to spinner(Its not a button) so I cannot hook disableTouch() on click of spinner!

Comment: Edited answer , Sorry that was mistake you can pass any parameter to function as long as its view. Just call `disableTouch()` in your  `onTouch()`

Comment: The point is when you will call disableTouch()? If we call it after the creation of spinner there is no use as after CLICK_DELAY of time after creation the spinner will be enabled. You cannot call it with onClickListener as spinner doesn't support it!

Comment: Edited answer again . I haven't asked you to set `onClickedListener`

Comment: Thanks a lot @N J. But for some reason it will not raise the click event with this and manually I have to add it like v.performClick(); in the place of //do your other stuff here. But this will fail in handling orientation for menu opened from spinner(menu disappears after orientation change. In default case the orientation works fine.).